# Тестирование класса angular

Tags: юнит-тесты, angular

Есть некий клас с зависимостями, не могу понять как тестировать такие вещи

```
import scrollTo from './scroll';
import {Renderer2, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { IScrollData } from './scroll-data.interface';
export default class TabsExtension {
 constructor(
  private renderer: Renderer2,
  private el: ElementRef
  ) {}
public configuration;
private prevButton;
private nextButton;
private buttonsWrap;

public init(wrap): void {

 this.generateButtons();
 this.appendButtonsToParent();
 this.addEventListeners(wrap);
 this.addTextToButtons();
 this.addClassesToElements();
}

private generateButtons() {

 this.prevButton = this.renderer.createElement('button');
 this.nextButton = this.renderer.createElement('button');
 this.buttonsWrap = this.renderer.createElement('div');

 this.renderer.appendChild(this.buttonsWrap, this.prevButton);
 this.renderer.appendChild(this.buttonsWrap, this.nextButton);

}

private appendButtonsToParent() {
  const parent = this.el.nativeElement.parentNode;
  const refChild = this.el.nativeElement;
  this.renderer.insertBefore(parent, this.buttonsWrap, refChild);

}

private scrollElement(to, element) {
  const scrollData: IScrollData = {
   element,
   to,
   duration: this.configuration.scrollTime || 500,
   direction: this.configuration.direction
};
 scrollTo(scrollData);
}

private addEventListeners(wrapper): void {

  const scrollWidth = wrapper.nativeElement.scrollWidth;
  this.renderer.listen(this.prevButton, 'click', () => {
  this.scrollElement(-scrollWidth, wrapper.nativeElement);
  });
  this.renderer.listen(this.nextButton, 'click', () => {
    this.scrollElement(scrollWidth, wrapper.nativeElement);
  });
}


private addTextToButtons(): void {
  const prevText = 
  this.renderer.createText(this.configuration.buttonPrevText || '');
  const nextText = 
  this.renderer.createText(this.configuration.buttonNextText || '');
  this.renderer.appendChild(this.prevButton, prevText);
  this.renderer.appendChild(this.nextButton, nextText);
}


private addClassesToElements(): void {
  this.renderer.addClass(this.prevButton, 
  this.configuration.buttonPrevClass || '');
  this.renderer.addClass(this.nextButton, 
  this.configuration.buttonNextClass || '');
  this.renderer.addClass(this.buttonsWrap, 
  this.configuration.buttonsWrapClass || '');
 }

}
```

Comment: эм, а что это такое вообще? что вы пытаетесь протестировать? зачем вы вручную создаете элементы?

Comment: От этого класа буду наследоваться компоненты. Есть такое у меня требование как покрытие тестами... Этот клас один из модуля для табов которые можно скролить. Собственно элементы которые создаются это кнопки при нажатии на которые можно будет проскролить эти табы.

Comment: @overthesanity Естьидеи как это можно сделать, или варианты переписать этот клас какнибудь по другому?

Comment: зачем вы это делаете вручную если у вас есть Angular? =)

Comment: тут даже покрывать нечего, я вам так скажу, тест кейсов нету,  используйте Angular для таких вещей